# Excel replace the -1 character in Find and Replace

Tags: python, regex, excel, python-2.7

Is it possible in Excel to find a string and then replace all of the found characters and the immediately preceding one?

The reason I'm asking is to try and replace 'variable text Façade Repairs' with 'variable text Facade Repairs' without actually typing the non-ASCII 'ç'. I've tried the SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text) function which won't let me use a wildcard in the old_text field to grab the ç and also Find and Replace function which lets me use a wildcard in the search, but then replaces the entire string instead of just 'Facade'.

I'd like to avoid using ç because this is being written in a python module and causing problems whenever I go to import that module elsewhere. (I've already also tried declaring the encoding in the python script, # coding=utf-8, and was thinking of trying to tackle the problem in Excel before it even gets to python).

Thanks for any input!

ANSWER: Thanks to selllikesybok, I was able to substitute all of the values for a column into a temp column without the ç and then copy/paste values from there back to the original column.

```
# -- substitutes non ascii c --
# populates Z column with ascii chars
for i in range(lastRow):
    excel.Cells(i+1, 26).Value = '=SUBSTITUTE(D'+str(i+1)+', CHAR(231), "c")'
# copies z 
excel.Range('Z1:Z'+str(lastRow)).Select()
excel.Selection.Copy()
# pastes values to d
excel.Range('D1:D'+str(lastRow)).Select()
excel.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)   # -4163 = Paste Values
# clears z
excel.Range('Z1:Z'+str(lastRow)).Select()
excel.Selection.Clear()
# resets view to top
excel.Range('A2').Select()
excel.Selection.Clear()
```

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and win32com for Excel commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Excel solution, you're looking for the `CHAR()` function:

If the string you're looking to alter is in A1, this would do the trick:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(231),"c")`

I know Excel way better than Python, but you could probably do something similar in your python code (refer to the codepoint rather than the character, to avoid having the actual non-ascii character written in the .py file).